# Scheduled JobIntentService never starts on API >= 27 Oreo

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-8.1-oreo, jobintentservice

I've got a widget that schedules a job and I have result: RESULT_SUCCESS from JobScheduler.schedule(job), but my service never starts. I waited more than 30 minutes.

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.tac.widgetproject">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".WidgetOne"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>

        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider"/>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".ServiceWidgetOne"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
</application>
```

WidgetOne class (kotlin)

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*

class WidgetOne : AppWidgetProvider() {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "Widget"

        // static method
        fun getCallingPendingIntent(context: Context): PendingIntent {
            val manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            val componentName = ComponentName(context, ServiceWidgetOne::class.java)
            val ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName)
            val updateIntent = Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)
                    .putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        super.onEnabled(context)
        ServiceWidgetOne.manageJobScheduler(context, true)
    }

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
        Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate()")

        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_one)
        val savedTime = Prefs().getLastNewsDate(context)
        val timeText = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.SHORT).format(Date(savedTime))
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, timeText)
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        super.onDisabled(context)
        Prefs().saveLastNewsDate(context, 0)
        ServiceWidgetOne.manageJobScheduler(context, false)
    }

}
```

ServiceWidgetOne class (kotlin)

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.job.JobInfo
import android.app.job.JobScheduler
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService
import android.util.Log

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class ServiceWidgetOne : JobIntentService() {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ServiceWidgetOne"
        private const val TIME_INTERVAL = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES
        private const val JOB_ID = 65276

        @TargetApi(N) // static method
        fun manageJobScheduler(context: Context, isOn: Boolean) {

            val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
            if (isOn) {
                val componentName = ComponentName(context, ServiceWidgetOne::class.java)
                val job = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName)
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                        .setPeriodic(TIME_INTERVAL)
                        .build()
                val jobResult = jobScheduler.schedule(job)
                Log.i(TAG, "Job #$JOB_ID activated: ${if (jobResult == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS)
                    "successful" else "with Error"}")
            } else {
                jobScheduler.cancel(JOB_ID)
                Log.i(TAG, "Job #$JOB_ID canceled")
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onHandleWork")        
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I do nothing.
When I put a widget to the homescreen in logs I have:

```
 I/ServiceWidgetOne: Job #65276 activated: successful
```

and nothing more :( My service never starts

I tried in Manifest:

```
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
```

But it has no effect
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are using `JobIntentService` which should be started using [JobIntentService.enqueueWork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html#enqueueWork(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)). Either that or extend JobService instead.

Comment: Tell me please, can I start JobService manually from my onEnable widgets method without notification inside JobService? I need a first initializing of widgets view from my database.

Comment: Yes you can, just like you are doing now. But your class `ServiceWidgetOne` is not `JobService`, it's extending `JobIntentService`. These are not the same.

Comment: I replaces my JobIntentService into JobService, and it's start normal, but I can't start it manually. If I use context.startForegroundService() it needs to call startForeground() with notification inside. That's why I used JobIntentService, cause I can call it by enqueueWork()

Comment: That's true. If you need to start that service immidietly, you can try to set `builder.setOverrideDeadline(0)`. That should work as far as device is not in doze mode.